# Unable to request js file in Meteor package

Tags: xmlhttprequest, meteor, package

For a css file in a Meteor package, I can request it by going to

```
localhost:3000/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

But for a js file, I can't do this

```
localhost:3000/packages/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
```

Why is that?

Comment: you should be able to get it at localhost:3000/packages/bootstrap.js , if you view page source you will get a list of all the JS files. For packages all the JS files will be combined. Note in a deployed app (one not started with meteor) all the JS files and all the CSS files will be combined into 1 each (try viewing page source on meteor.com for example).

Comment: I couldn't get the js file. It seems like the default behavior is different for different extension type in my browser. For example, the css would be displayed as raw text, js would not be recognized at all  and other file types will be downloaded as a file. When I change the extension type of my js file, everything works; but this seems like a bad hack.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You shouldn't need to access those files from the browser.

Comment: I need to load some soundfont files from the package inside my app after the document.body is available.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Web Inspector, it should show all of the JS files included on the page and where they are located.